# Javascript && and || operators and in line ternary functions produces INSANE results

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
var str = '1' || '2'
```

console.log(str) outputs 1
Okay... makes sense. The 1 is front of the '||', so it should never matter what comes after the '||'

```
var str = '1' || (true) ? '2' : '3'
```

console.log(str) outputs 2
...WHAT?! This should never happen. The '1' was in front of the '||'

```
var str = '1' || (false) ? '2' : '3'
```

console.log(str) outputs 2
...Okay JS go home you're obviously drunk.

Comment: I'm surprised it's even evaluating after the `||` -- when I recently tried this, I had to group all my statements after the OR statement to get the desired result: `var str = nullString || ( (boolStringTest)? 'stringA' : 'stringB' );`

Comment: _"console.log(str) outputs 2 ...WHAT?! This should never happen."_ Why not? `1` is truthy so the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: Look up operator precedence. You look at these examples under false assumptions.

Comment: so, `'1' || (true)` is evaluating first to be true/false statement -- THEN it's looking for the values? For better readability, the code is thinking: `var str = ( '1' || (true/false) )? '2' : '3'; ` ?

Comment: This question is related to operators precedence and type conversion, there is no answer which is describing both, i wrote an answer but question is closed now, so could not post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log('1' || (true) ? '2' : '3');
//is interpreted as 
console.log(('1' || true) ? '2' : '3');
//you mean to write
console.log('1' || (true ? '2' : '3'));
```

Answer (score 3):

What you expect is

`'1' || ((true) ? '2' : '3')`

, but basically what you are making is

`('1' || (true)) ? '2' : '3'`

You are creating shorthand for if statement where left part is evaluated and then proper value is returned, thus `'1'` is evaluating to true and this way you are getting `'2'` as a result